# Как из клиентской части перекинуть переменную в серверную часть?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars

Мне нужна рандомная генерация вопросов в одном .js файле, чтоб потом в нем же по id проверять input checkbox и в конце выводить результат. А для быстроты вывода вопросов использую .handlebars. В общем, мне нужно сделать тест.

*На всякий случай **server.js***

```
const express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const routes = require("./routes/index");
app.listen(3000);
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.engine(
  "handlebars",
  exphbs({
    defaultLayout: "main",
  })
);
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
app.use("/", routes);
```

У меня есть **data.json** файл с вопросами (их больше на самом деле, на 1000)

```
(data = [
  {
    "ids": "1",
    "question": "Правила технической эксплуатации железной дороги в Республике Беларусь устанавливают:",
    "answers": [
      "требования к организации функционирования, обслуживанию",
      "технической эксплуатации сооружений и устройств железнодорожного транспорта",
      "требования по сигнализации на железнодорожном транспорте",
      "технологические процессы организации движения поездов, их приема и отправления, работы диспетчера поездного, маневровой работы на железнодорожных станциях",
      "порядок (регламент) переговоров и действий работников железнодорожного транспорта при поездной и маневровой работе"
    ],
    "correct": [1, 2, 3, 4]
  },
  {
    "ids": "2",
    "question": "Правила технической эксплуатации железной дороги в Республике Беларусь обязательны для выполнения:",
    "answers": [
      "всеми организациями, выполняющими работы (оказывающие услуги) для пользователей железнодорожного транспорта",
      "индивидуальными предпринимателями, выполняющими работы (оказывающие услуги) для пользователей железнодорожного транспорта",
      "всеми работниками железнодорожного транспорта"
    ],
    "correct": [1, 2, 3]
  },
```

Я его открываю в своем **public/js/app.js** и делаю рандом вопросов

```
var mydata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
//let ses = document.getElementById("1");
let questi = []; // <------- это должно отправляться в index.js

for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  questi[i] = mydata[Math.floor(Math.random() * mydata.length)];
}
console.log(questi);
```

Но не знаю как **questi** отправить в **routes/index.js**

```
const express = require("express"),
  fs = require("fs"),
  router = express.Router();
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("test", {
    style: "main",
    quests: questi, // <------------- как-то открыть редактированный json из app.js тут
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Возможно ли как-то по-другому это все сделать, чтоб мой **test.handlebars** легко мог принимать значения

```
{{#each quests}}
<div id={{ids}}>
    <ul>
        <h3>{{question}}</h3>
        {{#each answers }}
        <li><input type="checkbox" id={{../ids}}_{{@key}} value="{{@key}}">{{.}}</li>
        {{/each}}
        <hr>
    </ul>
</div>
{{/each}}
<p>Отвечено:</p>
```

*И на всякий случай **main.handlebars***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>{{title}}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/{{style}}.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  {{{body}}}
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Понимаю, что глупо это все использовать в клиентской части, так как можно вычислить правильные ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать `fetch`-`POST`-`json` в конце опросника на какой-то специальный роут.

А правильные ответы хранить в другом `json`.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Сделал отдельную ссылку под json и через fetch оттуда брал нужные значения